# What does "I don't mind no (something)" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I can't understand what *"I don't mind **no** answer"* means exactly.
The context is: someone asks a question, and then, without waiting for an answer, says *"I don't mind no answer either"*.

Does it mean that the person also doesn't know the answer, and wants to know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is: someone asks a question, and then, without waiting for an answer, says "I don't mind no answer either".

That means: I do not mind if you **don't give me an answer**.

Or: **No answer** is fine, too.

That said, this is a spoken form, and does not work in writing.